# Unexpected result when concatenating strings of cells in (geo)pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, geopandas

I am working the data provided here https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/transport_verkehr/unfallatlas/

I am trying to create a concatenated string like this

```
import geopandas
accidents2020 = gp.read_file("Unfallorte2020_LinRef.shp")
accidents2020['joined'] = f"{accidents2020['ULAND']}{accidents2020['UREGBEZ']}{accidents2020['UKREIS']}{accidents2020['UGEMEINDE']}"
```

However, this gives me some weird string

```
0         0         12\n1         12\n2         12\n3   ...
1         0         12\n1         12\n2         12\n3   ...
2         0         12\n1         12\n2         12\n3   ...
3         0         12\n1         12\n2         12\n3   ...
4         0         12\n1         12\n2         12\n3   ...
```

which is unexpected. When I do a `accidents2020['ULAND']`

```
0         12
1         12
2         12
3         12
4         12
```

there are no `\n1`. Where are the `\n1` etc. coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accidents2020['ULAND']` is a Series, if you convert this Series to a string, it also includes the index and the linefeeds at the end of each line:

```
print(repr(f"{accidents2020.loc[0:1, 'ULAND']}"))
# '0    12\n1    12\nName: ULAND, dtype: object'

print(f"{accidents2020.loc[0:1, 'ULAND']}")
# 0    12
# 1    12
# Name: ULAND, dtype: object
```

> When I do a `accidents2020['ULAND']` there are no `\n1`.

No, they *are* there - you simply don't see them as `\n` representations but as linefeeds in the output.

> Where are the `\n1` etc. coming from?

`\n` is the newline character and `1` is the row index.

So what you need is simply `accidents2020['joined'] = accidents2020['ULAND'] + accidents2020['UREGBEZ'] + accidents2020['UKREIS'] + accidents2020['UGEMEINDE']`, without any f strings.

An alternative is [`cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) where you can optionally specify a separator: `accidents2020['joined'] = accidents2020['ULAND'].str.cat(accidents2020[['UREGBEZ', 'UKREIS', 'UGEMEINDE']])`